# How to define a TypeScript function that returns a subset of properties from an object based on a filter?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the code below.

```js
interface IEmployee {
    ID: string
    Employee: string
    Phone: number
    Town: string
    Email: string
    Name: string
}

// Should have all IEmployee properties 
let allProps = findOne<IEmployee>("ID = 1234234")

// Should be of type Pick<IEmployee, "Email"| "Phone">  
let picked = findOne<IEmployee>("ID = 1234234", ["Email", "Phone"])
```

How do you declare `findOne`?
Is it even possible to achieve, keeping the same calling code as above?

## Possible solutions

### With arrays(Preferred, not working)

The implementation below doesn't work, since `typeof fields[number]` will be `Array<keyof T>`

```js
function findOne<T>(filter: string, fields: Array<keyof T> =[]): Pick<T,typeof fields[number]> {
    return db.select(filter, fields)
}
```

### Adding a second generic parameter (Works)

This works, but is not easily readable

```js
function select<T, K extends Partial<T> = T>(filter: string, fields = Array<keyof K>): K {
    return db.select(filter, fields)
}

const props = ["Email", "Phone"] as const
type propsType = Pick<IEmployee, typeof props[number]>

let allProps = select<IEmployee>("Employee: 1234234")
let picked = select<IEmployee, propsType>("Employee: 1234234")
```

Comment: This is a great question and a hard problem. You might want to look into TS 5 which is shipping a new feature called "const Type Parameters" https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0-beta/#const-type-parameters

Comment: You need to have two type parameters, but TypeScript will not let you manually specify one and then infer the other (that would require *partial type argument inference* as requested in [ms/TS#26242](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)).  Workarounds involve either currying or including a dummy function input, both shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJA3Rm).  Personally I find currying to be the most intuitive, especially when you save the intermediate result as a `findOneIEmployee` function. Does this fully address your q? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That's it! First time I see currying, thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, you need `findOne()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in two type parameters: `T` corresponding to the base object type you're finding, and `K` corresponding to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of keys from `T` you want to pick.  In *theory* that would look like

```
declare const findOne: <T, K extends keyof T>(
  query: string, keys?: K[]
) => { [P in K]: T[P] }
```

But there's a problem.  You want to manually *specify* `T` when you call `findOne()`, and you also want the compiler to *infer* `K` from the `keys` argument without requiring that you specify it.  Unfortunately, Typescript doesn't support this sort of *partial type argument inference*.  Either you have to specify all the type arguments, or the compiler can try to infer all the type arguments.  (Note that giving `K` a [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) does *not* enable partial type argument inference; its true that you don't have to manually specify an argument with a default, but the compiler will still not infer it for you; it will just fall back to the default.)

---

There is a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) for partial type argument inference.  Maybe one day you'll be able to write

```
// NOT VALID TS, DON'T TRY THIS
declare const findOne: <T, K extends keyof T = infer>(
  query: string, keys?: K[]
) => { [P in K]: T[P] }
```

But until and unless this is ever implemented, you will need to work around it.

The workaround I prefer in cases like this is to [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the function; that is, split the single function with two type parameters into a function of one type parameter that *returns* a function with another type parameter.  Like this:

```
declare const findOne: <T>() => <K extends keyof T>(
  query: string, keys?: K[]
) => { [P in K]: T[P] }
```

Now you can call `findOne` and manually specify `<T>`, and when you call the returned function then `K` will be inferred:

```
let allProps: IEmployee = findOne<IEmployee>()("ID = 1234234")
let picked = findOne<IEmployee>()("ID = 1234234", ["Email", "Phone"])
// let picked: { Phone: number;  Email: string; }
```

It is a bit weird to have that extra function call in there, but it works!  And once you start using curried functions this way you'll find it easier to store the intermediate result and reuse it:

```
const findOneIEmployee = findOne<IEmployee>();
allProps = findOneIEmployee("ID = 1234234");
picked = findOneIEmployee("ID = 1234234", ["Email", "Phone"]);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&downlevelIteration=true&removeComments=true&importHelpers=true&target=99&inlineSourceMap=false#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-xlBguVxudxxH0dhK9pNBbwp8LhSN9IgFWODbogTvDwMjEIRVJpdINDLGzPFbMWvtcR3cti8PmQNAUmGCQlCrhEkWisXiiTO9s+2TUY2qdQaTXGHS6PXC9cIal2Y36g2GQjGbUIUxmCyW5VFaw2IC2O26+0OESiMTiyBtSUnmAbaZeDzDL3j1D550u11u9zQj5IyYdEHya9bx-CBCzJKNs1jZERFfRMhT-T5AKnO8SDAzNoxzVY82MXBGSLVl2Wg6huV5VE4OFFYWQlKVlCgOVDHzRUBHYFVyyAA)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after. But here is one variant of findOne.

```
interface Dog {
  name: string
  age: number
  breed: string
  id: number
}

const dogs: Dog[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Rex',
    age: 3,
    breed: 'German Shepherd'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Fido',
    age: 4,
    breed: 'Golden Retriever'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Spot',
    age: 5,
    breed: 'Poodle'
  }
]

function findOne<DataType, KeyType extends keyof DataType>(
  filter: [KeyType, keyof KeyType],
  items: DataType[],
  keys: KeyType[]
): Partial<DataType> | undefined {
  for (const item of items) {
    if (item[filter[0]] === filter[1]) {
      return {
        ...keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
          return {
            ...acc,
            [key]: item[key]
          }
        }, {})
      }
    }
  }
}

const dog = findOne(['age', 5], dogs, ['id', 'age'])

returns {
   id: 3, age: 5
}
```

And to make everything more clear we can make filter as an object:

```
function findOne<DataType, KeyType extends keyof DataType>(
  filter: {
    key: KeyType
    value: keyof KeyType
  },
  items: DataType[],
  keys: KeyType[]
): Partial<DataType> | undefined {
  for (const item of items) {
    if (item[filter.key] === filter.value) {
      return {
        ...keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
          return {
            ...acc,
            [key]: item[key]
          }
        }, {})
      }
    }
  }
}

const dog = findOne(
  {
    key: 'id',
    value: 2
  },
  dogs,
  ['id', 'age']
)
```

Comment: In my case I wouldn't have `items: DataType[]` available (`dogs: Dogs[]`). If we remove the `items` as parameters it goes back to having `findOne<Dogs, "id"| "age">(keys, dogs, ['id', 'age']`